# Getting access to rust's std library constants

Tags: rust

I am trying to get the "std" value for `pi/2` which I can see in the official docs and the code [1](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f64/primitive.f64.html).

i have tried variations on the following but without luck

```
let p2: f64 = std::f64::FRAC_PI_2; // fixme
let p2: f64 = std::f64::frac_pi_2(); // fixme
let tmp: f64 = 1.0; // tmp variable
let p2: f64 = tmp.frac_pi_2(); // fixme
let p2: f64 = 3.1415926536897932384626/2.0; // what my current code does now
```

I think there is something basic about how `consts` literals and the std library is used that I am not quite groaking.

P.S.

This is part of my first rust program trying to implement the cordic method as have been my last few questions on SO, the code is located [here](https://github.com/Victory/cordic-sin-in-rust).

Comment: Also, the value of pi you have there is wrong. The 10th decimal place should be a `5`, not `6`. :)

Comment: @Dogbert, omg? Forget about your very good answer below, how could you pick up that error? Is it a known bug, or did memorise or ... *mind blown*.

Comment: @Dogbert - well i am very impressed that you could see that. Luckily for simpletons like myself, we can now use `std::f64::consts::PI`! Also my cordic implemented in rust now works! https://github.com/Victory/cordic-sin-in-rust/blob/master/cordic-sin/src/main.rs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `frac_pi_2` exists in the `std::num::Float` trait. You can call it like:

```
let p2: f64 = std::num::Float::frac_pi_2()
```

Alternatively, this constant also exists as `std::f64::consts::FRAC_PI_2`, which you can use directly.

Code:

```
fn main() {
    let p2: f64 = std::num::Float::frac_pi_2();
    println!("{}", p2)
    println!("{}", std::f64::consts::FRAC_PI_2);
}
```

Output:

```
1.570796
1.570796
```

[Demo](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20p2%3A%20f64%20%3D%20std%3A%3Anum%3A%3AFloat%3A%3Afrac_pi_2%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20p2%29%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20std%3A%3Af64%3A%3Aconsts%3A%3AFRAC_PI_2%29%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert! Can you help me a bit on terminology, "std" is the namespace, "f64" is a library and "consts" is another namespace? Or how would you call each of the parts of the `std::f64::consts` name?

Comment: `std` is a **crate**. `f64` is a **module** at the root of the `std` crate. `consts` is an inner module in the `std::f64` module. See the [Crates and Modules Guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-crates.html) for more information.